# I can't start a golang server

Tags: go, server

I downloaded https://github.com/Jhuster/RTCStartupDemo/tree/master/RTCSignalServer

Now I want to make this run on my VPS but I dont know how.
It is written in Golang/go.
So I installed go on my VPS in linux ubuntu.
Now when I run in the directory:

source env.sh

make

It gives me the following error message:

```
GOPATH = /RTCSignalServer
make[1]: Entering directory '/RTCSignalServer'
making for mac
pattern ./src/rtc.signal.com/app/...: directory prefix src/rtc.signal.com/app does not contain main module or its selected dependencies
make[1]: *** [Makefile:10: mac] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/RTCSignalServer'
make: *** [Makefile:5: all] Error 2
```

Now I tried to make a module of main.go in src/app/ directory but it still doesnt work.
Could someone please help me and give me the commands I should run?
Thank you.

Comment: To run a Go application on a server, just build it, then copy the binary to the server and run it like you would any other binary. You don't need Go installed on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you I build it like this and it worked:

```
$ cd RTCSignalServer
$ go env -w GO111MODULE=off
$ source env.sh
$ make
```